# Can I play on my Xbox Live account on my mates Xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops, xbox-network

I'm around at my mates place and its Double XP weekend on COD: Black Ops.

Can I play on my Xbox account on his Xbox so I can boost my XP points instead of his?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can either bring a memory card over with your profile on it or use the Recover Gamertag feature. You can also bring your harddrive over if you don't have a memory card.

Comment: thanks anna! were using the recovery feature as my xbox is back at home. cheers!

Comment: If you plan on doing this regularly you are much better off using a memory card/USB stick to store your gamer profile as otherwise you have to do Recover Gamertag every time you switch between machines